# @Transactional AspectJ Advice

Tags: spring, aspectj

I added my custom @Around advice to bean's method. Bean is transactional. How can I make by advice to run within the transaction?

I use AspectJ to add advices.

Advice code:

```java
@Aspect
@Order(200)
public class MyAdvice {
    @Around
    public Object wrap(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object ret = pjp.proceed();
        // some processing that requires a transaction
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Bean code:

```java
public class MyBean {
  // method is wrapped by MyAdvice.wrap
  @Transactional
  public Object someBusinessMethod() {
     // ...
  }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" order="100" mode="proxy" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

I need the `MyAdvice.wrap` to run within the same transaction as `MyBean.someBusinessMethod`.

Comment: Are you using full AspectJ on just Spring AOP ? And I can't see the pointcut declaration ...

Comment: I use both AspectJ and Spring AOP. Pointcut is omitted.

Comment: Omitting information, but expecting an answer is somewhat counterproductive...

Comment: Pointcut is not required to explain the problem. I omitted it to minimize the sample code.